# Porting application from ASP.NET To ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I am trying to figure out what to take into consideration before porting my whole application to MVC 3.
I heard it built better for the web.
I'd like to point out that my current website is based heavily on the Membership API, Roles etc.. Built-In with the .NET framework.

Will everything work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC also uses ASP.NET pipelines - so most of HttpModule base stuff works with ASP.NET MVC.

However, actual handler works quite differently - ASP.NET Webforms uses Page and Control trees while ASP.NET MVC uses completely different approach - controller handling request and view used for html generation. There is certainly a learning curve involved for migrating to ASP.NET Webforms to ASP.NET MVC.

You should be asking yourself what exactly would you gain by migrating to ASP.NET MVC - for example, do you get a lot of enhancements and viable life span is more than 2-3 years. These might be the few reasons for considering migration.

Answer (score 1):

Let me pull out my crystal ball.  Since you really don't give much information, I'll have to read your mind...  Hmmmm.... all signs point to no.

Yes, membership works fine in MVC, but porting an app from webforms could mean a lot of issues, particularly if you rely on third party controls.